# Formula to indicate how many cells to add in a sum

Tags: excel-formula, sum, google-sheets-formula, formula

Pls assist with a formula if you can. Let's say a have a line of numbers - A1 to A10. In B1 to B10 I have the numbers 1 to 10. I want to write a formula which will calculate the sum of the number of cells indicated. Let's say I input '5' - the formula must take A1 + A2 + A3 + A4 + A5 = result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A"&D2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`=SUM(A1:INDEX(A:A,C1))`
Where `C1` is your input value (used as the row number for the index).

This does the same as the formula suggested by player0, but in Excel `INDIRECT` is volatile, which will recalculate if any change is made anywhere in the workbook, which can slow down Excel.